# WebStorm does not use a tsconfig.json file

Tags: typescript, webstorm, tsconfig

I cannot understand whether WebStorm uses the `tsconfig.json` configuration file at all. I see that there are enough questions on this topic on the platform, but for some reason they all do not solve my problem. To explain what I expect, I will first demonstrate my WebStorm configurations:
[image]

My configuration file is not placed in the root where the IDE is initialized, but this does not make sense because nothing has changed during initialization in the WebStorm tape folder:

[image]

I expected that WebStorm will use this file, since it is the only one in the project (despite those in node_modules, but I don't think that the IDE is looking for it there) for code inspection and subsequent output of errors or warnings directly in the editor, I do it myself `tsc`:
[image]

I thought that WebStorm is capable of inspection like **PhpStorm** when with similar `CodeSniffer` settings in the `Editor/Inspections` tab you could choose the PSR standard or your rules file, but here with `TypeScript` it seems to me that everything is much simpler because we use static options according to the TS documentation. Therefore question - does WebStorm even know how to highlight errors using the `tsconfig.json` file?
Now I have the feeling that it just doesn't see my `tsconfig.json` file for some reason, because when I select the item in the context menu "Compile TypeScript" it displays the following:
[image]

But as I indicated above, `tsc` found as many as 9 errors, and if I understand correctly, it should use the `Node interpreter` from the settings, and the node image that I use there looks directly into the tape directory.

Comment: WebStorm uses the nearest `tsconfig.json` current file is included in for compiling, traversing the folders hierarchy from current folder up to the IDE project root. If your current file is not included in any `tsconfig.json`, the default compiler options are used for compiling this file. `b` or `-p` options in Typescript settings are not taken into account

Comment: @lena Thank you for answering. Can you be more specific about what is meant by *"If your current file is not included in any tsconfig.json, the default compiler options are used for compiling this file"*. In the question I wrote that my `tsc` uses the same interpreter specified in TS config WebStorm, `tsc` sees tsconfig.json WebStorm does not. So I don't quite understand what I missed(